# Scraping website only gets me 20 results, but there should be more

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i'm trying to understand why my soup.find_all only returns 20 results, even though there should be more of those.

```
#Site
url = 'https://www.fairprice.com.sg/promotions'

#requests
headers = {'user-agent': 'my-agent/1.0.1'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

#bs4
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
mydivs = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "sc-1plwklf-10 jNMebL"})

len(mydivs)
Output: 40
```

Searched through the sites and have realised it may be due to the page loading the products after scrolling down. Is there a workaround for this? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting 20 items as output because rest of data are dynamically populated by JavaScript as GET method from API.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

experiments = ('searchVariant-B,timerVariant-Z,inlineBanner-A,'
               'substitutionBSVariant-A,gv-A,SPI-Z,SNLI-B,SC-B,'
               'shelflife-C,A')

params = dict(experiments=experiments,
              includeTagDetails='true',
              orderType='DELIVERY',
              pageType='promotion',
              storeId=165,
              )

url = 'https://website-api.omni.fairprice.com.sg/api/product/v2'

result=[]
for params['page'] in range(1, 6):
    data = requests.get(url, params).json()
    for item in data['data']['product']:
        name = item['name']
        result.append({"Product name": name})
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                    Product name
0                               Pasar Fresh Eggs
1                     Meiji Fresh Milk - Regular
2     FairPrice DeluxSoft Bathroom Tissue (3ply)
3                              Fresh Blueberries
4         UFC Refresh 100% Natural Coconut Water
..                                           ...
95                Magnum Mini Ice Cream - Almond
96  Clorox Toilet Bowl Cleaner Tablets - Tru Blu
97     Kleenex Facial Tissue Box - Floral (3ply)
98                    Fairprice Scouring Sponge 
99        Prego Pasta Sauce - Traditional Tomato

[100 rows x 1 columns]
```

[screenshot of api url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQQzi.png)

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I edited your very nice answer to break out the query parameters in a slightly more maintainable way.

Comment: Thank you so much! As someone that has no experience with html/css/js, could you share briefly how the experiments, url and params was derived?

Comment: You can handle querysting parameters in severals ways, in payload  it's sent by key-value pairs, in url  it is used directlly, experiments is nothing but a key  of query stiring parameters, the editor makes a bit complex, I used direct url for a bit more make easy to understand. You also can use query strings parameters as params where it lies key value pairs. You can take ideas about it from here:  https://indianpythonista.wordpress.com/2016/12/10/get-and-post-requests-using-python/

Comment: Thank you! Lastly, where did you find the direct url that u provided in ur solution? Through the dev tools? The one i used was the customer facing site (https://fairprice.com.sg)

Comment: @user8729612, See the above screenshot

Comment: overlooked the link, appreciate the help!