# Not getting all results when web scraping deliveroo

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am trying to web scrape all resturant names on deliveroo when entering a postcode, i have somewhat managed to do this with the following code but the issue is i only get 20 or so results, but on deliveroo theres nearly 100 resturants.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# get the page
url = 'https://deliveroo.co.uk/restaurants/oxford/port-meadow?geohash=gcpn7n35zy89&sort=distance'
page = requests.get(url)

# parse the page
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# find the element with tag "li" and class "HomeFeedUILines-8bd2eacc5b5ba98e"
results = soup.findAll("li", {"class": "HomeFeedUILines-8bd2eacc5b5ba98e"})

# scrape all the "p" elements inside and get the text attribute
for result in results:
    ps = result.findAll("p")
    for p in ps:
        print(p.text)
```

i believe someone else faced a similar issue but i do not understand their answer and how i'd implement it:
[Scraping website only gets me 20 results, but there should be more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72130434/scraping-website-only-gets-me-20-results-but-there-should-be-more).

Also found someones github project that does something similar but much more complex and the code seems to break at the cookie clicking part:https://github.com/SelvinSelbaraju/deliveroo-web-scraper/blob/main/Deliveroo%20-%20Web%20Scraper%20and%20Data%20Analysis.ipynb

Comment: your hyperlinks are wrong; check the urls

Answer (score 1):

Why scrape the frontend when you have direct access to their GraphQL API; I just took a look out of curiosity and before scraping anything I generally check if there's a way to tap into the feed of the DOM rather than scrape the DOM itself (often scraping the DOM is not reliable and can be inconsistent, prone to errors, etc.);

By looking at the AJAX call made when filtering these results, I noticed that GraphQL network request which has all the data you need passing it right into the DOM - that would be the best live feed to tap into; the results are 1.11MB so all your restaurants are surely there.

See the GraphQL python request below, you can consume this JSON and parse the results as you loop through the nested arrays and viola - all your data is there.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://api.uk.deliveroo.com/consumer/graphql/"

payload = json.dumps({
  "query": "\n      query getHomeFeed(\n        $ui_actions: [UIActionType!]\n        $ui_blocks: [UIBlockType!]\n        $ui_controls: [UIControlType!]\n        $ui_features: [UIFeatureType!]\n        $ui_layouts: [UILayoutType!]\n        $ui_layout_carousel_styles: [UILayoutCarouselStyle!]\n        $ui_lines: [UILineType!]\n        $ui_targets: [UITargetType!]\n        $ui_themes: [UIThemeType!]\n        $fulfillment_methods: [FulfillmentMethod!]\n        $location: LocationInput!\n        $url: String\n        $options: SearchOptionsInput\n        $uuid: String!\n      ) {\n        results: search(\n          location: $location\n          options: $options\n          url: $url\n          capabilities: {\n            ui_actions: $ui_actions,\n            ui_blocks: $ui_blocks,\n            ui_controls: $ui_controls,\n            ui_features: $ui_features,\n            ui_layouts: $ui_layouts,\n            ui_layout_carousel_styles: $ui_layout_carousel_styles,\n            ui_lines: $ui_lines\n            ui_targets: $ui_targets,\n            ui_themes: $ui_themes,\n            fulfillment_methods: $fulfillment_methods\n          }\n          uuid: $uuid\n        ) {\n          layoutGroups: ui_layout_groups {\n            id\n            subheader\n            data: ui_layouts { ...uiHomeLayoutFields }\n          }\n\n          controlGroups: ui_control_groups {\n            appliedFilters: applied_filters { ...uiControlAppliedFilterFields }\n            filters { ...uiControlFilterFields }\n            sort { ...uiControlFilterFields }\n            queryResults: query_results { ...uiControlQueryResultFields }\n            fulfillmentMethods: fulfillment_methods { ...uiControlFulfillmentMethodFields }\n          }\n\n          modals: ui_modals {\n            ...uiModalFields\n            ...uiChallengesModalFields\n            ...uiPlusFullScreenModalFields\n          }\n\n          overlays: ui_feed_overlays {\n            ...uiFeedOverlayFields\n          }\n\n          meta {\n            ...searchResultMetaFields\n          }\n        }\n\n        \n  fulfillmentTimes: fulfillment_times(\n    capabilities: {\n      ui_actions: $ui_actions,\n      ui_blocks: $ui_blocks,\n      ui_controls: $ui_controls,\n      ui_features: $ui_features,\n      ui_layouts: $ui_layouts,\n      ui_layout_carousel_styles: $ui_layout_carousel_styles,\n      ui_lines: $ui_lines\n      ui_targets: $ui_targets,\n      ui_themes: $ui_themes,\n      fulfillment_methods: $fulfillment_methods\n    }\n    fulfillment_methods: $fulfillment_methods\n    location: $location\n    uuid: $uuid\n  ) {\n    fulfillmentTimeMethods: fulfillment_time_methods {\n      fulfillmentMethodLabel: fulfillment_method_label\n      fulfillmentMethod: fulfillment_method\n      asap {\n        ...fulfillmentTimeOptionFields\n      }\n      days {\n        day\n        dayLabel: day_label\n        times {\n          ...fulfillmentTimeOptionFields\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n\n      }\n      \n  fragment fulfillmentTimeOptionFields on FulfillmentTimeOption {\n    optionLabel: option_label\n    selectedLabel: selected_label\n    timestamp(format: UNIX)\n    selectedTime: selected_time {\n      day\n      time\n    }\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiControlFulfillmentMethodFields on UIControlFulfillmentMethod {\n    label\n    targetMethod: target_method\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment searchResultMetaFields on SearchResultMeta {\n    location {\n      cityName: city_name\n      cityUname: city_uname\n      isoCode: country_iso_code\n      countryName: country_name\n      geohash\n      lat\n      lon\n      neighborhoodUname: neighborhood_uname\n      neighborhoodName: neighborhood_name\n      postcode\n    }\n    options {\n      fulfillmentMethod: fulfillment_method\n      deliveryTime: delivery_time\n      params {\n        id\n        value\n      }\n      query\n    }\n    restaurantCount: restaurant_count {\n      results\n      location\n    }\n    searchPlaceholder: search_placeholder\n    title\n    collection {\n      linkTitle: link_title\n      targetParams: target_params {\n        ...uiTargetParamsFields\n      }\n      previousTargetParams: previous_target_params {\n        ...uiTargetParamsFields\n      }\n      searchBarMeta: search_bar_meta {\n        searchBarPlaceholder: search_bar_placeholder\n        searchBarParams: search_bar_params {\n          id\n          value\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    uuid\n    web {\n      url\n    }\n    warnings {\n      type: warning_type\n    }\n    searchPills: search_pills {\n      id\n      label\n      placeholder\n      params {\n        id\n        value\n      }\n    }\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiTargetFields on UITarget {\n    typeName: __typename\n    ... on UITargetRestaurant {\n      ...uiTargetRestaurant\n    }\n    ... on UITargetParams {\n      ...uiTargetParamsFields\n    }\n    ... on UITargetAction {\n      action\n    }\n    ... on UITargetMenuItem {\n      ...uiTargetMenuItem\n    }\n    ... on UITargetDeepLink {\n      webTarget: fallback_target {\n        uri: url\n      }\n    }\n    ... on UITargetMenuItemModifier {\n      ...uiTargetMenuItemModifier\n    }\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiBlockFields on UIBlock {\n    typeName: __typename\n    ... on UIBanner {\n      key\n      header\n      caption\n      backgroundColor: background_color {\n        ...colorFields\n      }\n      buttonCaption: button_caption\n      contentDescription: content_description\n      target {\n        ...uiTargetFields\n      }\n      images {\n        icon {\n          ...iconFields\n        }\n        image\n      }\n      theme: ui_theme\n      trackingId: tracking_id\n      trackingProperties: tracking_properties\n    }\n    ... on UIButton {\n      key\n      text\n      contentDescription: content_description\n      target {\n        ...uiTargetFields\n      }\n      theme: ui_theme\n      trackingId: tracking_id\n      trackingProperties: tracking_properties\n    }\n    ... on UIShortcut {\n      key\n      images {\n        default\n      }\n      name\n      contentDescription: content_description\n      nameColor: name_color {\n        ...colorFields\n      }\n      backgroundColor: background_color {\n        ...colorFields\n      }\n      target {\n        ...uiTargetFields\n      }\n      theme: ui_theme\n      trackingId: tracking_id\n    }\n    ... on UICard {\n      key\n      trackingId: tracking_id\n      trackingProperties: tracking_properties\n      theme: ui_theme\n      contentDescription: content_description\n      border {\n        ...uiCardBorderFields\n      }\n      target {\n        ...uiTargetFields\n      }\n      uiContent: properties {\n        default {\n          ...uiHomeCardFields\n        }\n        expanded {\n          ...uiHomeCardFields\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    ... on UIMerchandisingCard {\n      key\n      headerImageUrl: header_image_url\n      backgroundImageUrl: background_image_url\n      contentDescription: content_description\n      uiLines: ui_lines {\n        ...uiLines\n      }\n      cardBackgroundColor: background_color {\n        ...colorFields\n      }\n      buttonCaption: button_caption\n      target {\n        ...uiTargetFields\n      }\n      trackingId: tracking_id\n    }\n    ... on UICategoryPill {\n      ...uiCategoryPillFields\n    }\n    ... on UITallMenuItemCard {\n      ...uiTallMenuItemCardFields\n    }\n    ... on UIStoryCard {\n      ...uiStoryCardFields\n    }\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiHomeLayoutFields on UILayout {\n    typeName: __typename\n    ... on UILayoutCarousel {\n      header\n      subheader\n      style\n      imageUrl: image_url\n      target {\n        ...uiTargetFields\n      }\n      uiLines: ui_lines {\n        ...uiLines\n      }\n      targetPresentational: target_presentational\n      key\n      blocks: ui_blocks {\n        ...uiBlockFields\n      }\n      trackingId: tracking_id\n      rows\n    }\n    ... on UILayoutList {\n      header\n      key\n      blocks: ui_blocks {\n        ...uiBlockFields\n      }\n      trackingId: tracking_id\n    }\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiControlFilterFields on UIControlFilter {\n    id\n    header\n    images {\n      icon {\n        name\n        image\n      }\n    }\n    optionsType: options_type\n    options {\n      count\n      default\n      name: header\n      id\n      selected\n      target_params {\n        ...uiTargetParamsFields\n      }\n    }\n    styling {\n      web {\n        desktop {\n          collapse\n        }\n        mobile {\n          collapse\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiControlAppliedFilterFields on UIControlAppliedFilter {\n    label\n    target_params {\n      ...uiTargetParamsFields\n    }\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiTargetParamsFields on UITargetParams {\n    params {\n      id\n      value\n    }\n    queryParams: query_params\n    title\n    typeName: __typename\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiTargetRestaurant on UITargetRestaurant {\n    restaurant {\n      id\n      name\n      links {\n        self {\n          href\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    typeName: __typename\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiTargetMenuItem on UITargetMenuItem {\n    menuItem: menu_item {\n      id\n    }\n    links {\n      href\n    }\n    typeName: __typename\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiTargetMenuItemModifier on UITargetMenuItemModifier {\n    restaurantId: restaurant_id\n    menuItemId: menu_item_id\n    uiTargetType: ui_target_type\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiControlQueryResultFields on UIControlQueryResult {\n    header\n    key\n    resultTarget: result_target {\n      ...uiTargetFields\n    }\n    targetPresentational: result_target_presentational\n    trackingId: tracking_id\n    options {\n      key\n      count\n      highlights {\n        begin\n        end\n      }\n      uiLines: ui_lines {\n        ...uiLines\n      }\n      image {\n        type: __typename\n        ... on DeliverooIcon {\n          ...iconFields\n        }\n        ... on UIControlQueryResultOptionImageSet {\n          default\n        }\n      }\n      label\n      isAvailable: is_available\n      target {\n        ...uiTargetFields\n      }\n      trackingId: tracking_id\n    }\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment colorFields on Color {\n    hex\n    r: red\n    g: green\n    b: blue\n    a: alpha\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment colorGradientFields on ColorGradient {\n    from {\n      ...colorFields\n    }\n    to {\n      ...colorFields\n    }\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment iconFields on DeliverooIcon {\n    name\n    image\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment illustrationBadgeFields on DeliverooIllustrationBadge {\n    name\n    image\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiHomeCardFields on UICardFields {\n    bubble {\n      uiLines: ui_lines {\n        ...uiLines\n      }\n    }\n    overlay {\n      background: background {\n        typeName: __typename\n        ...colorFields\n        ...colorGradientFields\n      }\n      text {\n        position\n        color {\n          ...colorFields\n        }\n        value\n      }\n      promotionTag: promotion_tag {\n        primaryTagLine: primary_tag_line {\n          backgroundColor: background_color {\n            ...colorFields\n            ...colorGradientFields\n          }\n          text {\n            ...uiLines\n          }\n        }\n        secondaryTagLine: secondary_tag_line {\n          backgroundColor: background_color {\n            ...colorFields\n            ...colorGradientFields\n          }\n          text {\n            ...uiLines\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    favouritesOverlay: favourites_overlay {\n      id\n      entity\n      isSelected: is_selected\n      backgroundColor: background_color {\n        ...colorFields\n        ...colorGradientFields\n      }\n      selectedColor: selected_color {\n        ...colorFields\n      }\n      unselectedColor: unselected_color {\n        ...colorFields\n      }\n      target {\n        ...uiTargetFields\n      }\n      countData: count_data {\n        count\n        isMaxCount: is_max_count\n      }\n    }\n    countdownBadgeOverlay: countdown_badge_overlay {\n      backgroundColor: background_color {\n        ...colorFields\n      }\n      uiLine: ui_line {\n        ...uiLines\n      }\n    }\n    image\n    uiLines: ui_lines {\n      ...uiLines\n    }\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiTextLine on UITextLine {\n    typeName: __typename\n    key\n    uiSpans: ui_spans {\n      ...uiSpansPrimitive\n      ... on UISpanCountdown {\n        endsAt: ends_at\n        isBold: is_bold\n        size\n        key\n        color {\n          ...colorFields\n        }\n      }\n      ... on UISpanTag {\n        key\n        uiSpans: ui_spans {\n          ...uiSpansPrimitive\n        }\n        backgroundColor: background_color {\n          ...colorFields\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiLines on UILine {\n    typeName: __typename\n    ... on UITextLine {\n      ...uiTextLine\n    }\n    ... on UITitleLine {\n      key\n      text\n      color {\n        ...colorFields\n      }\n      size\n    }\n    ... on UIBulletLine {\n      key\n      iconSpan: icon_span {\n        typeName: __typename\n        color {\n          ...colorFields\n        }\n        icon {\n          ...iconFields\n        }\n        iconSize: size\n      }\n      bulletSpacerSpan: bullet_spacer_span {\n        typeName: __typename\n        width\n      }\n      uiSpans: ui_spans {\n        ...uiSpansPrimitive\n      }\n    }\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiSpansPrimitive on UISpan {\n    typeName: __typename\n    ... on UISpanIcon {\n      key\n      color {\n        ...colorFields\n      }\n      icon {\n        ...iconFields\n      }\n      iconSize: size\n    }\n    ... on UISpanSpacer {\n      key\n      width\n    }\n    ... on UISpanText {\n      key\n      color {\n        ...colorFields\n      }\n      text\n      isBold: is_bold\n      textSize: size\n    }\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiCardBorderFields on UICardBorderType {\n    topColor: top_color {\n      ...colorFields\n    }\n    bottomColor: bottom_color {\n      ...colorFields\n    }\n    leftColor: left_color {\n      ...colorFields\n    }\n    rightColor: right_color {\n      ...colorFields\n    }\n    borderWidth: border_width\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiModalButtonFields on UIModalButton {\n    title\n    theme: ui_theme\n    dismissOnAction: dismiss_on_action\n    target {\n      typeName: __typename\n      ... on UITargetWebPage {\n        url\n        newWindow: new_window\n      }\n      ... on UITargetAction {\n        action\n        params {\n          id\n          value\n        }\n      }\n      ... on UITargetParams {\n        ...uiTargetParamsFields\n      }\n    }\n    trackingId: tracking_id\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiModalFields on UIModal {\n    typeName: __typename\n    header\n    caption\n    image {\n      ... on UIModalImage {\n        image\n      }\n      ... on DeliverooIcon {\n        ...iconFields\n      }\n      ... on DeliverooIllustrationBadge {\n        ...illustrationBadgeFields\n      }\n    }\n    buttons {\n      ...uiModalButtonFields\n    }\n    theme: ui_theme\n    displayId: display_id\n    trackingId: tracking_id\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiChallengesModalFields on UIChallengesModal {\n    typeName: __typename\n    displayId: display_id\n    trackingId: tracking_id\n    challengeDrnId: challenges_drn_id\n    mode\n    smallView: small_view {\n      header\n      bodyText: body_text\n      infoButton: info_button {\n        ...uiModalButtonFields\n      }\n      icon {\n        ... on UIChallengesIndicator {\n          required\n          completed\n        }\n        ... on UIChallengesBadge {\n          url\n        }\n        ... on UIChallengesSteppedIndicator {\n          steps {\n            ... on UIChallengesSteppedStamp {\n              text\n              icon\n              isHighlighted: is_highlighted\n            }\n          }\n          stepsCompleted: steps_completed\n          stepsRequired: steps_required\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    fullView: full_view {\n      header\n      headerSubtitle: header_subtitle\n      bodyTitle: body_title\n      bodyText: body_text\n      confirmationButton: confirmation_button {\n        ...uiModalButtonFields\n      }\n      infoButton: info_button {\n        ...uiModalButtonFields\n      }\n      icon {\n        ... on UIChallengesIndicator {\n          required\n          completed\n        }\n        ... on UIChallengesBadge {\n          url\n        }\n        ... on UIChallengesSteppedIndicator {\n          steps {\n            ... on UIChallengesSteppedStamp {\n              text\n              icon\n              isHighlighted: is_highlighted\n            }\n          }\n          stepsCompleted: steps_completed\n          stepsRequired: steps_required\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiPlusFullScreenModalFields on UIPlusFullScreenModal {\n    typeName: __typename\n    displayId: display_id\n    trackingId: tracking_id\n    image {\n      typeName: __typename\n      ... on UIModalImage {\n        image\n      }\n      ... on DeliverooIllustrationBadge {\n        ...illustrationBadgeFields\n      }\n    }\n    header\n    body\n    footnote\n    primaryButton {\n      ...uiModalButtonFields\n    }\n    secondaryButton {\n      ...uiModalButtonFields\n    }\n    confetti\n    displayOnlyOnce: display_only_once\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiFeedOverlayFields on UIFeedOverlay {\n    id\n    position\n    blocks: overlay_blocks {\n      ... on UIFeedOverlayBanner {\n        typeName: __typename\n        id: display_id\n        trackingId: tracking_id\n        header\n        caption\n        isDismissible: is_dismissible\n        theme: ui_theme\n        image {\n          ... on DeliverooIllustrationBadge {\n            name\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiCategoryPillFields on UICategoryPill {\n    typeName: __typename\n    blocks: content {\n      ...uiLines\n    }\n    backgroundColor: background_color {\n      typeName: __typename\n      ...colorFields\n    }\n    target {\n      ...uiTargetFields\n    }\n    trackingId: tracking_id\n    contentDescription: content_description\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiTallMenuItemCardFields on UITallMenuItemCard {\n    id: menu_item_id\n    title\n    key\n    image\n    target {\n      ...uiTargetFields\n    }\n    price {\n      ...currencyFields\n    }\n    trackingId: tracking_id\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment currencyFields on Currency {\n    code\n    formatted\n    fractional\n    presentational\n  }\n\n      \n  fragment uiStoryCardFields on UIStoryCard {\n    preview {\n      profile {\n        imageUrl: image_url\n        headingLines: heading_lines {\n          ...uiLines\n        }\n      }\n      video {\n        sources {\n          url\n          type\n        }\n        placeholderImage: placeholder_url\n        autoplay\n        trackingId: tracking_id\n      }\n      overlay {\n        typeName: __typename\n        ... on UIStoryTextOverlay {\n          background {\n            typeName: __typename\n            ...colorFields\n            ...colorGradientFields\n          }\n          uiLines: ui_lines {\n            ...uiLines\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      target {\n        ...uiTargetFields\n      }\n    }\n    main {\n      profile {\n        imageUrl: image_url\n        headingLines: heading_lines {\n          ...uiLines\n        }\n      }\n      video {\n        sources {\n          url\n          type\n        }\n        placeholderImage: placeholder_url\n        autoplay\n        trackingId: tracking_id\n      }\n      overlay {\n        typeName: __typename\n        ... on UIStoryButtonOverlay {\n          background {\n            typeName: __typename\n            ...colorFields\n            ...colorGradientFields\n          }\n          contentLines: content {\n            ...uiLines\n          }\n          button {\n            key\n            text\n            contentDescription: content_description\n            target {\n              ...uiTargetFields\n            }\n            theme: ui_theme\n            trackingId: tracking_id\n            trackingProperties: tracking_properties\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    trackingId: tracking_id\n    trackingProperties: tracking_properties\n    key\n  }\n\n    ",
  "variables": {
    "ui_blocks": [
      "BANNER",
      "CARD",
      "SHORTCUT",
      "BUTTON",
      "MERCHANDISING_CARD",
      "STORY_CARD"
    ],
    "ui_controls": [
      "APPLIED_FILTER",
      "FILTER",
      "SORT"
    ],
    "ui_layout_carousel_styles": [
      "DEFAULT",
      "PARTNER_HEADING"
    ],
    "ui_lines": [
      "TITLE",
      "TEXT",
      "BULLET"
    ],
    "ui_targets": [
      "PARAMS",
      "RESTAURANT",
      "MENU_ITEM",
      "WEB_PAGE",
      "DEEP_LINK"
    ],
    "fulfillment_methods": [
      "DELIVERY",
      "COLLECTION"
    ],
    "location": {
      "geohash": "gcpn7n35zy89",
      "city_uname": "oxford",
      "neighborhood_uname": "port-meadow",
      "postcode": ""
    },
    "options": {
      "query": "",
      "web_column_count": 4,
      "user_preference": {
        "seen_modals": [
          {
            "id": "nc_promos_voucher_take10",
            "timestamp": 1674830243
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "url": "https://deliveroo.co.uk/restaurants/oxford/port-meadow?sort=distance&geohash=gcpn7n35zy89",
    "uuid": "7270af10-2722-4bda-b041-d768208912c6",
    "ui_actions": [
      "CHANGE_DELIVERY_TIME",
      "CLEAR_FILTERS",
      "NO_DELIVERY_YET",
      "SHOW_MEAL_CARD_ISSUERS",
      "SHOWCASE_PICKUP",
      "TOGGLE_FAVOURITE",
      "COPY_TO_CLIPBOARD",
      "SHOW_PICKUP",
      "SHOW_DELIVERY",
      "REFRESH",
      "SHOW_VIDEO_STORIES",
      "SHOW_HOME_MAP_VIEW",
      "ACCEPT_CHALLENGES",
      "SHOW_CHALLENGES_DETAILS"
    ],
    "ui_features": [
      "UNAVAILABLE_RESTAURANTS",
      "LIMIT_QUERY_RESULTS",
      "UI_CARD_BORDER",
      "UI_CAROUSEL_COLOR",
      "UI_PROMOTION_TAG",
      "UI_BACKGROUND",
      "ILLUSTRATION_BADGES",
      "SCHEDULED_RANGES",
      "UI_SPAN_TAGS",
      "UI_SPAN_COUNTDOWN",
      "HOME_MAP_VIEW"
    ],
    "ui_themes": [
      "BANNER_CARD",
      "BANNER_EMPTY",
      "BANNER_MARKETING_A",
      "BANNER_MARKETING_B",
      "BANNER_MARKETING_C",
      "BANNER_PICKUP_SHOWCASE",
      "BANNER_SERVICE_ADVISORY",
      "CARD_LARGE",
      "CARD_MEDIUM",
      "CARD_MEDIUM_HORIZONTAL",
      "CARD_SMALL",
      "CARD_SMALL_DIAGONAL",
      "CARD_SMALL_HORIZONTAL",
      "CARD_WIDE",
      "CARD_TALL",
      "CARD_TALL_GRADIENT",
      "MODAL_DEFAULT",
      "MODAL_PLUS",
      "MODAL_BUTTON_PRIMARY",
      "MODAL_BUTTON_SECONDARY",
      "MODAL_BUTTON_TERTIARY",
      "SHORTCUT_DEFAULT",
      "SHORTCUT_STACKED",
      "SHORTCUT_HORIZONTAL",
      "BUTTON_PRIMARY",
      "BUTTON_SECONDARY",
      "ANY_MODAL"
    ],
    "ui_layouts": [
      "LIST",
      "CAROUSEL"
    ]
  }
})
headers = {
  'authority': 'api.uk.deliveroo.com',
  'accept': 'application/json, application/vnd.api+json',
  'accept-language': 'en',
  'authorization': '',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'origin': 'https://deliveroo.co.uk',
  'referer': 'https://deliveroo.co.uk/',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  'x-roo-client': 'consumer-web-app',
  'x-roo-client-referer': '',
  'x-roo-country': 'uk',
  'x-roo-external-device-id': '',
  'x-roo-guid': '76ff73aa-cf71-47eb-aeaf-ada8b6c400c1',
  'x-roo-session-guid': 'cdd20a08-5740-49b0-ba93-90f58def6d43',
  'x-roo-sticky-guid': '76ff73aa-cf71-47eb-aeaf-ada8b6c400c1',
  'Cookie': '__cf_bm=nWG7YHerxVjA.cYSDMt6MA4YytsDozK3asJXqyb5A.8-1674830393-0-AbXU1uPHJZDRHZhTAIgJDvPdu7i8l4jypJWlcqs5f091IupaQEClXx3fWikwZpO80QD3SWYBeZQB9YiUpCAC0KBdTvgpY7KNwZlPufclBwSM'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Give it a shot and you'll see what I mean :)